# Working with CheckBox in ListView and Filterable on Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, filter

From this tutorial (http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/08/filter-custom-listviewbaseadapter.html), I am able to filter items in `ListView` according to `EditText` input:

The result works perfectly as expected. However when I try to put `CheckBox` in `ListView` item, things get a little out of hand. Below are my modification of source code from the tutorial.

**Country.java**

```
public class Country {

    String name;
    String iso_code;
    int flag;
    Boolean checked;

    Country(String name, String iso_code, int flag, Boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.iso_code = iso_code;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String getIso_code() {
        return iso_code;
    }

    public void setIso_code(String iso_code) {
        this.iso_code = iso_code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public Boolean getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Country> countrylist;
    ArrayList<Country> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    CustomAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Country> countrylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countrylist = countrylist;
        mStringFilterList = countrylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countrylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return countrylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return countrylist.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent ) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            TextView name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView iso_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            Country country = countrylist.get(position);

            name_tv.setText(country.getName());
            iso_tv.setText(country.getIso_code());
            iv.setImageResource(country.getFlag());

            cb.setChecked(country.getChecked());
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        country.setChecked(isChecked);
    }
});


        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Country> filterList = new ArrayList<Country>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ( (mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase() )
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Country country = new Country(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getName() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getIso_code() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getFlag());

                        filterList.add(country);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            countrylist = (ArrayList<Country>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When being filtered, the state of `CheckBox` jumps almost always randomly. I assume because the value of checked in `Country` changes upon in runtime. Any idea how to implement this in correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't update the view if convertView already exists. You should do, the only thing to skip is reinflating. (The viewholder pattern would improve this code greatly by the way).

Because you never update the view it means it displays  the data for whatever was at that position previously.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent ) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    CheckBox cb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                country.setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }

    TextView name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    ...
    cb.setChecked(country.getChecked());
    return convertView;
}
```

The above code looks to me like it should fix your problem, but be forgiving about formatting, I'm editing it from my phone. In future you could look into the checkable interface and listviews using it, should save you a bit of code (and headache)